# Latitude/longitude from PostGIS table with coordinates transformation not working

Tags: postgis, latitude-longitude

I have a PostGIS (PostgreSQL 13/PostGIS 3.1.1 on Debian 11.7) table with points in EPSG:6708, so it's plain coordinates (data from Northern Italy).
I need to get lat/long coordinates, so I do:

```
    SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom) AS xy, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(the_geom,4326)) AS ll FROM acq_impianti WHERE gid=426;
                         xy                     |                    ll                     
    --------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------
     POINT(291349.5482259364 5072882.274108588) | POINT(52.9750863624063 2.074122662821441)
```

which is absolutely wrong; in fact if I do the same transformation using [this tool](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3857&t_srs=4326&x=NaN&y=NaN), I obtain:
[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong....

EDIT:
Using ST_FlipCoordinates solves the problem, but maybe there is a better way to handle this

```
SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom) AS xy, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_FlipCoordinates(the_geom),4326)) AS ll FROM acq_impianti WHERE gid=426;                     xy                     |                     ll                      
--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------
 POINT(291349.5482259364 5072882.274108588) | POINT(12.316072170259908 45.77796903086367)
```

Comment: are you sure the data  in the table is stored in the correct projection?

Comment: Probably some confusion with x/y order but I can't say where. EPSG:6708 is a northing-easting system.

Comment: Its definitely an X/Y vs Y/X problem, I tried it both ways round in R and in one order get the value in the question and the other gets the value in the screenshot...

Comment: OK, is there a way to "swap" X with Y?

Comment: Found it: using ST_FlipCoordinates!


SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom) AS xy, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_FlipCoordinates(the_geom),4326)) AS ll FROM acq_impianti WHERE gid=426;                     xy                     |                     ll                      
--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------
 POINT(291349.5482259364 5072882.274108588) | POINT(12.316072170259908 45.77796903086367)

I wonder if there is a cleaner solution....

Comment: Do you know how the data are inserted into the database? Maybe the coordinates have been swapped once then, and now you need to swap them again.

Comment: Investigate a bit more, as it seems there is no need to swap the coordinates UNLESS 1) data is not in 6708 or 2) definition of 6708 has been modified (which could include a bug in proj). `select ST_AsText(ST_Transform(st_setsrid('POINT(291349 5072882)'::geometry,6708),4326));` --> ` POINT(12.316065244416027 45.777966400818336)` (POSTGIS="3.3.3 3.3.3" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="150" GEOS="3.11.2-CAPI-1.17.2" PROJ="8.2.1" LIBXML="2.9.14" LIBJSON="0.16" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap the X & Y coordinates like this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_geom_column = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_Y(your_geom_column ), ST_X(your_geom_column )), ST_SRID(your_geom_column))
WHERE your_condition = whatever;
```

Hope it helps my friend. In geom